# app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php not found laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I cannot find app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php file in laravel 5.4. I am trying to configure the route in the file but I cannot find it in 'Middleware' folder. It is listed in Kernel.php file though.

Comment: have you run this command ? 
php artisan make:auth

Comment: @rodrane.. yes I've

Answer (score 5):

Authenticate middelware is located at following path

> your_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php